# Caixa ao passar mouse em cima do municipio

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Estou utilizando a api do GoogleMaps3 e após renderizar o mapa gostaria que ao passar o mouse em cima de alguma área(que já foi programado) mostra-se o código da área.
O que eu fiz até agora foi:

passar o mouse em cima da área:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(setores[codarea], 'mouseover', function(){
                        this.setOptions({
                            fillOpacity:0.3,
                            strokeWeight: 2
                        });
                        mostrartexto(this.id);
                    });
```

mostrartexto

```
function mostrartexto(codmun)
    {
        var msg = codmun;
        if (msg)
        {
            $("body").append('<div id="mostrartexto"></div>');
            $("#mostrartexto").html(msg);
        }
    }
```

css de mostrartexto

```
$("#mostrartexto").css({
                "margin-left": e.pageX+15,
                "margin-top": e.pageY+5
            });
```

Desta forma não está funcionando,alguém tem alguma dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodolfo blz??

Então eu não sei se eu entendi bem o que você esta precisando, então eu criei um pequeno exemplo:

http://jsbin.com/cevate/1/edit?html,output

Participe da nossa comunidade Google Maps Api Brasil

https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102409361642970934842

Comment: ,vou participar sim e era isso que eu estava procurando.Obrigado